# IIS 6.1 - Always running web site with Hangfire for background jobs

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6, hangfire

I want to create an ASP.NET web site on IIS 6.1 (cannot be changed), that does not recycle nor shuts down. I want it to always be running and never be down not even for a second.

Are there any built-in features that can help me achieve this?

(I cannot create a Windows Service. I need a web site.)

The workaround and less preferable solution would be creating a regular web site and creating a windows scheduled task that calls a function in that web site in a fixed interval so it never recycles.

Do you know if IIS 7.* or IIS 8 support such a functionality?

** EDIT

It will be a web site running Hangfire for the background tasks.
Of course the Windows Service + Hangfire solution is better but because the lack of time and to keep it simple for our developers it is easier for us to maintain a web site which runs background jobs.

Comment: Check out the Advanced Settings of the AppPool in the IIS Manager. You can configure Recycling and Idle TimeOut settings there.

Comment: Recycling typically overlaps so the service is always running, it may just be in different processes.  Whats the rationale for needing to customize this behavior?

Comment: I want to create a background service that does internal maintenance operations, but for the simplicity and delivery times of developing a web site, I wanted to avoid creating a Windows Services. Maintaining and updating a Windows Service is more complex than a web site project and I wanted a fast and simple solution, and because our developers work on web site projects all the time, I wanted to keep it simple for them.

Of course creating a Windows Service combined with Hangfire would be preferable but I want to check the Web Site + Hangfire option

Comment: You could create a scheduled task that calls a url that kicks off the maintenance.

Comment: I thought of it but Hangfire is a better solution for me. The scheduled task would be used for waking up the web site each x minutes before it recycles and shuts down.

Comment: You can think Hangfire as "easier", "better" and "preferable", but that is just the beginning of nightmares IMHO. It completely goes against the design of IIS/ASP.NET. Take your time.

Comment: @LexLi What do you mean when you say nightmares? and what do you think is preferrable?

Comment: "I cannot create a Windows Service." But that's simply the way you should go.

Comment: @LexLi Lets say I create a Windows Service. I still will be using Hangfire. So by what you said there will be a lot of complications using it. Why did you say that about Hangfire?

Comment: You develop an application that needs certain complications. Hangfire is an open source project that utilizes its own understanding of IIS/ASP.NET, which personally I disagree in every aspects. Not to mention if you Google around tons of issues are there about this framework. Enjoy whatever you choose, as you will take responsibilities from then on.

Comment: @LexLi Could you elaborate about the disagreement points? Why is it so bad? It seems to work for so many people.
Could you give me an alternative to Hangfire for .NET? Using a Windows Service is only the method, but still I will have to create a queue system that queues jobs and with complex issues that other more mature frameworks already fixed

Comment: @LexLi you haven't answered my last question. Could you elaborate a bit more so we all can understand. Could you offer a better alternative to Hangfire for complex background jobs in a large scale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the framework, framework version, etc there might be different configurations that need to be accounted.

The best approach would be to check the [official docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html) that asses this exact problem.
For example, if you build a .NET Core app, the steps for keeping an app alive are:

- Managed pipeline mode: `Integrated`
- Set start mode to “Always Running”.
- Set Idle Time-Out (minutes) to 0.
- Set `Preload Enabled = True`
- Go to the Configuration Editor on your app, and navigate to `system.webServer/applicationInitialization`. Set the following settings:

`doAppInitAfterRestart: True`
Open up the Collection… ellipsis. On the next window, click Add and enter the following:

- hostName: {URL host for your Hangfire application}
- initializationPage: {path for your Hangfire dashboard, like /hangfire}

Answer (score 3):

Under the app pool set the idleTimeout to 0. That will disable idle timeout recycling.